# Copying all files in CD Rom and saving them in a folder at a different location using win32 c++

Tags: c++, file, winapi, copy, cd-rom

Is there a way in win32 C++ that I can copy all the files inside a CD Rom and save them in a folder located somewhere else (where the folder location will be specified)? Is there a win32 C++ function to do this? The docs show the function SHFileOperationA() but can this copy all the files in a CD Rom?

Comment: The filesystem doesn't really care about the difference between a CDROM vs a HDD. Those differences are handled at the hardware level. As long as you have 2 filesystem folder paths, one to the CDROM drive and one elsewhere, you can easily copy files from one to the other using `SHFileOperation()`, `IFileOperation`, `CopyFile()`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau CDROMs do use a different filesystem (typically ISO9660) than hard disks, but the shell functions happily abstract this away.  Of course it is still possible to see some effects, such as loss of files differing on in name case when copying from a case-sensitive to a case-preserving-but-insensitive filesystem.  Or small changes in creation date due to different precision.

Comment: And then there are the tricks used for copy-protection, such as files listed in the directory but pointing to addresses that don't physically exist on the CD.  These can wreak havoc on general-purpose directory copying functions.

Comment: CopyFile() wants you to specify the name of the file being copied though. What if you don't know the name of the files but you want it to copy all the files in the CD Rom and paste them in a folder at a different location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CopyFile() wants you to specify the name of the file being copied
> though. What if you don't know the name of the files

You can use [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea#return-value) and [`FindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea) combine with [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile).

Assume your CD ROM drive is `E:`, you can try the following example to see if it helps.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fData;
HANDLE searchHdl = FindFirstFile(L"E:\\*", &fData);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != searchHdl)
{
    do {
        std::wstring existingFileName(L"E:\\");
        existingFileName.append(fData.cFileName);

        std::wstring newFileName(L"D:\\");
        newFileName.append(fData.cFileName);

        if (CopyFile(existingFileName.c_str(), newFileName.c_str(), TRUE))
            wprintf(L"CopyFile success!\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"CopyFile fails with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    } while (FindNextFile(searchHdl, &fData));
}
FindClose(searchHdl);
```

Comment: Han Does CopyFile() work with folders also? What I have folders in the CD Rom and want to copy the folder and everything in it? Can CopyFile() do this?

Comment: @Sophia No, `CopyFile` doesn't copy folders. You may check [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) attribute to determine if it is a folder, if this is true create a folder with the same name in destination location.